# Unix(BSD Unix, MacOSX) vs Linux login setuid bit difference

Tags: linux, macos, unix, operating-system, computer-science

Under Unix (for example BSD Unix, MacOSX) the login program has the setuid bit set. In Linux login does not have the setuid bit set. 
The questions is about `/bin/login` .

What are the differences between the two architectural decisions and why Linux doesn't have to do it?
How does it solve the permissions' problem?

I've seen this as a CS questions somewhere and I can't figure out the answer. So please feel free to help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux you normally have a bunch of `getty` (text console) processes and/or a display manager (graphical) login process running with root privileges. When creating a user session, these are calling `/bin/login`, still with root privileges. `login` then drops the privileges by changing the UID/GID and `execv`-ing the login shell, or launching the graphical session.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate who calls the /bin/login when creating a user session in Unix(MacOS)?

Answer (score 0):

Linux ist also using SUID bit for passwd.
I work with Centos/Fedora and Ubuntu and all this distributions using SUID bit for passwd program.

Comment: OP is asking about `/bin/login` not passwd